# Jenkins slow multibranch pipeline scan for Gerrit repo

Tags: jenkins, gerrit

I’m using Jenkins master slave with Gerrit plugin. Multibranch scanning is taking very long (around 24mins) for a repo with around 80 remote branches and 750Mb in size. Jenkins master is running on version 2.319.3 with 8 vCPUs and 32GB memory. However, the resource usage is very low despite the scanning takes very long. I’ve also checked the disk IOPS and network both looks good. Manually execution of `git fetch` command in master takes only 45 seconds. Any reasons for the long branch indexing?

Comment: I've seen a similar issue.
Whenever we check in multiple commits (let's say 4-5 Gerrit changes), every commit will trigger 10 automated jobs (i.e. ~50 overall). Whenever this happens, a lot of these jobs will run into timeouts trying to check out the Git repository. Timeout means 10 minutes!!!
Did you ever find a solution to your problem?